# Authentication verification message is not displaying as a hyperlink in the mail but rather displaying as a text in the email

Tags: python, django

Under my views I have all my views for user authentication which includes: signin, signup, signout and other function views.

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage,send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from my_site.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode,urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes,force_str
from .tokens import generate_token
from .models import User 


# Create your views here.


def all(request):

    return render(request,'authentication/all_signups.html')


def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        fname = request.POST.get("fname")
        lname = request.POST.get("lname")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        password2 = request.POST.get("password2")


        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            messages.error(request, "Username already exist!")
            return redirect('home')
        
        if User.objects.filter(email=email):
            messages.error(request, "E-mail already exist!")
            return redirect('home')

        if len(username) > 15:
            messages.error(request, "Length of username too long!")
            return redirect('home')

        if password != password2:
            messages.error(request, "Passwords do not match!")
            return redirect('home')

        if not password.isalnum():
            messages.error(request, "Password must be alphanumeric!")
            return redirect('home')
          
        
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
        user.fname = fname 
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        


        # Welcome E-mail

        subject = 'Welcome to ADi meals mobile!'
        message = f'Hello {fname.capitalize()}, welcome to ADi meals mobile!\n\nThank you for visiting our website.\n\nWe have also sent you a confirmation email, please confirm your email address to login into your account.\n\n\n\nThanking you.\n\n\nVictoria Oluwaseyi\nC.E.O'
        from_email = EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [user.email]
        send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=True)


        #Email Confirmation 
        current_site = get_current_site(request) 
        email_subject = 'Confirm your email @ ADi meals mobile!'
        message2 = render_to_string('email_confirmation.html',{
            'name':fname,
            'domain':current_site.domain,
            'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': generate_token.make_token(user)
        }) 
        from_email2 = EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list2 = [user.email]

        #email = EmailMessage(
        #    email_subject,
        #    message2,
        #    from_email2,
        #    to_list2,
        #)
        #fail_silently = True
        #email.send()

        send_mail(email_subject,message2,from_email2,to_list2,fail_silently=True)


        messages.success(request,"Your account has been successfully created!\nWe have also sent you a confirmation email, please confirm your email address to login into your account.")
        
        return redirect('authentication:signin')

         
    return render(request,'authentication/signup.html')


def signin(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)


        if user is not None and user.is_active == False:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You have successfully logged in")
            fname = username
            return render(request,'authentication/landing_page.html',{'fname':fname})

        else:
            messages.error(request,"Bad credentials! or Check your mail to verify account!")
            return redirect('authentication:signin')


    return render(request,'authentication/signin.html')


def signout(request):

    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "You have successfully logged out!")
    return redirect('home')


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError,user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and generate_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True 
        fname = user.fname 
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Email has been verified successfully!")
        return render(request,'authentication/landing_page.html',{'fname':fname})

    else:
        return render(request, 'activation_failed.html')


def account_info(request):

    return render(request,'authentication/account_info.html',{'names':[request.user.username,request.user.first_name,request.user.last_name,request.user.email]})


def edit_account(request):

    return render(request,'authentication/edit_account.html')


def setpassword(request):

    return render(request,'authentication/setpassword.html')
```

Here is the html template I rendered to display the verification email message to the user.

email_confirmation.html

```
{% autoescape off %}

Welcome to ADi meals mobile!

Hello {{name | capfirst}}, 

Please confirm your email by clicking on the link below.

Confirmation link: http://{{domian}} <a href= "{% url 'authentication:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}">Click me</a>

{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the mail as Text, Emails default send in a text version and you need to use `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send an email in HTML format

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template

subject = 'My Subject'

plaintext = get_template('email_templates/textmail_fallback.txt')
htmly     = get_template('email_templates/htmlmail_prefered.html')

toList = ['test@mytest.com']

from_email = None
# from_email = 'MyDjangoSite@LocalHost'


# make email with text
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, plaintext.render(data), from_email, toList, reply_to=None, bcc=None, cc=None)
# Note: you can remove reply_to, bcc, cc, I'm just showing that those are options

# attach HTML email
msg.attach_alternative(htmly.render(data), 'text/html')

# send email
msg.send()
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

---

### Edit!!

**Note: you could also just change the type:**

- From the Docs, I missed it.

```py
msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```

I think using the Alternative method is still the way to go, as it's more universal.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Another question is how do I include the dict inside the get_template function? It doesn't seem to work when I add the "name", "domain", "uid", "token" inside it.

Comment: Sweet! glad you figured it out. I should have made that **data** more obvious.. i just copied it my my code and data was a parameter for the function